# sink function creating error while opening a file

Tags: r

I opened `R` as administrator. I have windows 8.1 OS. My working directory is "C:/Users/username/Documents" in which I have created a file called `test.txt`. I wanted to redirect the `R` output to this file. So I did this
    `sink("test.txt")`

But I got the following error.

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'test.txt': Permission denied
```

What could be the cause here. File does exist and I have opened `R` as an administrator. My `R` version is 3.1.3

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's your current working directory? Include a `print(getwd())` just to be sure. Also `Sys.info()["user"]` might help to confirm that you are running R with the user you think you are.

Comment: I have replaced my username with the string "username" ... for posting here. My username is same as my name.

Comment: So you're saying your user account is an administrator account? Or that you are trying to access another users's home directory files as an administrator? It's still not very clear.

Comment: When I start `R`, I right click on the icon and select "Run as Administrator".  I have logged in to my own account on windows 8.1, so I think I am using my user account as an administrator account. I have setup only one user on my laptop, which is me.

Comment: Is this unique to R and `sink()`? Can you `cat("test", file="text.txt")` to the file? Can your run Notepad as administrator and overwrite that file?

Comment: I tried that command and it didn't throw any warning or error. But it didn't write the string `test` to the file `test.txt`. I also did `cat("test", file="text.txt", append = TRUE)` and it didn't change the content of the file `test.txt`

Comment: Then it really sounds like you have the wrong working directory set. Check that value of `getwd()` just before you run the command.

Comment: I am sorry. The name of the file is "test.txt" and not "text.txt". When I run the command again ` cat("test", file="test.txt")` I get the following error.

Comment: Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'test.txt': Permission denied